# How do I change width of a widget in OnDemandGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I would like to change the width of a widget that I inserted into OnDemandGrid through dgrid/editor. The template file is setting the column by invoking `this.ruleLinesColumns()` which returns the columns returned by the function. I'm using the dgrid/editor plugin into the column via the following code. As default, the width of the widget is set to be a lot wider than the column width. I would like to set it to be 100% so that it would fit into the column rather than going over it.

Here are my files:

**Template File**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
         data-dojo-props="region: 'center', gutters: false">

        <div data-dojo-type="dgrid/OnDemandGrid" 
             data-dojo-mixins="dgrid/Selection, dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry, prophet/common/dgrid/_StandardGridMixin, prophet/common/dgrid/_TreeRowHighlightingMixin"
             data-dojo-attach-point="ruleLinesGrid"
             data-dojo-props="'class': 'grid',
                              store: this.ruleLinesStore,
                              columns: this.ruleLinesColumns(),
                              sort: 'sequence',
                              selectionMode: 'single',
                              deselectOnRefresh: false">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Where I'm setting the column**

```
ruleLinesColumns: function() {
    var self = this;
    return [
        ...
        editor({
            field: "training",
            label: msgs.editor.training,
            sortable: false,
            required: true,
            autoSave: true
        }, NumberTextBox),
        ...
    ];
},
```

I've tried several different things such as including `style: {width: '100%'}` and `width: '100%'` but nothing seems to work.

Here's the documentation for dgrid/editor:
https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/doc/components/mixins/Editor.md

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer!

Because the column widget is being passed in through the dgrid/editor, you can actually include all that you need to set for the NumberTextBox inside `editorArgs`.

For example, I had to get the **width of the widget to be 100%** and also make sure that the NumberTextBox can only input **positive integer** while making it **required**:

```
editor({
    field: "training",
    label: msgs.editor.training,
    sortable: false,
    autoSave: true,
    editorArgs: {
        required: true,    // Since required isn't part of editor's field, I had to put it into editorArgs as well
        constraints: {min: 0, places: 0},
        style: {width: '100%'}
    }
}, NumberTextBox),
```